# Why is this the true cardinality of this set?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let $$\mathbb{A} = \{0,1,2,....,n\}$$ and $$\mathbb{B} = \{0,-1,-2,...,-n\}$$ for some integer $$n\ge1.$$ Find the cardinality of $$\mathbb{A} \cup \mathbb{B}.$$ The cardinality is $2n+1$. I don't get how they came up with that. Can you please explain the steps here? Thanks.

Comment: What do you think it is?  Note the $0$ is common.

Comment: More generally, if $A$ and $B$ are any finite sets, then $|A\cup B|=|A|+|B|-|A\cap B|$ (where the vertical lines denote cardinality). In your case $|A|=n+1$, $|B|=n+1$ and $|A\cap B|=|\{0\}|=1$. So $|A\cup B|=(n+1)+(n+1)-1=2n+1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there are $n$ positive numbers in $\mathbb{A}$, an there are $n$ negative numbers in $\mathbb{B}$, and there is one zero appearing in both, so the total is
$$n+n+1=2n+1$$

Comment: Thank you, you really helped me out a lot!

Comment: You are most welcome.